# Haskell 'invalid type signature'

Tags: haskell

```
FilmsSorted :: [Film] -> [Film]  
FilmsSorted = reverse.sortBy sortFilm
```

i get this error, not sure on how to fix it? (below)

******.hs:89:1: error:
    Invalid type signature: FilmsSorted ::
    Should be of form  ::

invalid type signature?

Comment: Please post the full error/code fragment. What is `sortFilm` doing?

Comment: function names can not start with an uppercase letter in Haskell, rename your function to `filmsSorted` and _this_ error will go away

Answer (score 1):

Please post a full example, such as:

```
import Data.List (reverse, sortBy)
type Film = ()

FilmsSorted :: [Film] -> [Film]
FilmsSorted = reverse . sortBy sortFilm

sortFilm :: Film -> Film -> Bool
sortFilm = undefined
```

And a full, formatted, error:

```
GHCi, version 8.4.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded GHCi configuration from /Users/tommd/.ghci
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( x.hs, interpreted )

x.hs:4:1: error:
    Invalid type signature: FilmsSorted :: ...
    Should be of form <variable> :: <type>
  |
4 | FilmsSorted :: [Film] -> [Film]
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

At this point the error indicates your variable, `FilmsSorted`, is somehow incorrect.  The error, as @Cubic said, is that variables must start with lower case letters.  So try:

```
filmsSorted :: ...
filmsSorted  = ...
```